# Query Boolean error

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean, union-all, full-outer-join

I have a simple query, but I'm looking for the error for some time now.
The only thing I can think of that it would have a problem with connecting to the database, but that can't be right, because it is working on other parts of the website.

This is the db-connection:

```
$dbwebwinkel = mysql_connect("localhost", "abcdef", "123456") or die(mysql_error()); 
$db1 =mysql_select_db('abcdef', $dbwebwinkel) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is the error message:

> There is something wrong in the search-query ( SELECT prod_omschrijving.producttitel, prod_omschrijving.idproduct AS 'idproductom', producten.idproduct AS 'idproductprod', producten.productlink FROM prod_omschrijving FULL OUTER JOIN producten ON producten.idproduct=prod_omschrijving.idproduct WHERE prod_omschrijving.idproduct IS NULL OR producten.idproduct IS NULL)
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN producten ON producten.idproduct=prod_omschrijving.idproduct W' at line 8
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/paginas/boekingen/producten.php on line 61

This is the script.

```
$qry = "
SELECT
    prod_omschrijving.producttitel,
    prod_omschrijving.idproduct AS 'idproductom',
    producten.idproduct AS 'idproductprod',
    producten.productlink
 FROM
    prod_omschrijving
 FULL OUTER JOIN 
    producten 
 ON 
    producten.idproduct=prod_omschrijving.idproduct
 WHERE
    prod_omschrijving.idproduct IS NULL
 OR
    producten.idproduct IS NULL";

$sql = mysql_query($qry, $dbwebwinkel);
$sql = mysql_query($qry, $dbwebwinkel);
if($sql === false)
{
    echo (" Er gaat iets mis in de zoekquery (".$qry .")".mysql_error($dbwebwinkel));
}
else
{
    WHILE ($lijstje = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo $lijstje['idproductom'];
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't read that language the error is in. we are an english site.

Comment: mysql... FULL OUTER JOIN... eh?

Comment: Sorry

Er gaat iets mis in de zoekquery
Means
There is something wrong in the searchquery

Comment: There is no FULL OUTER JOIN in mysql - and note that php's mysql_ API is deprecated

Comment: thank you, well I have a serious problem about that mysql. I think I have about 10.000 used on my site. Going to be some work to alter them all. 
I did not know full outer join doesn't work, it was not a very important script, so better leave it alone then.

Comment: You have 10000 full outer joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `union all` and two outer joins:

```
SELECT o.producttitel, o.idproduct AS idproductom,
       p.idproduct AS idproductprod, p.productlink
FROM prod_omschrijving o LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     producten p
     ON p.idproduct = o.idproduct
WHERE p.idproduct IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT o.producttitel, o.idproduct AS idproductom,
       p.idproduct AS idproductprod, p.productlink
FROM prod_omschrijving o RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
     producten p
     ON p.idproduct = o.idproduct
WHERE o.idproduct IS NULL;
```

I added table aliases to make the query more readable.